# $\sup_{x\in B_r(z)}|\nabla u(x)|\geq cr$ for $\Delta u=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be open and bounded. Let $\Delta u=1$ in $U$.

Can you follow $\sup_{x\in B_r(z)}|\nabla u(x)|\geq cr$ provided $B_r(z)\subset\subset U$?

I thought about using the mean-value theorem but it didn't get me anywhere. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega_n$ denote the volume of the unit ball. The $(n-1)$-dimensional area of the surface of the unit ball is $n\omega_n$.  Apply Green's theorem on $B_r(z)$ denoting by $\nu$ the exterior normal vector:
$$ \omega_n r^n = \int_{B_r(z)} 1 \, dx = \int_{B_r(z)} \Delta u \, dx = \int_{\partial B_r(z)} \nabla u \cdot \nu \, ds \le n \omega_n r^{n-1}\max_{x \in \partial B_r(z)} |\nabla u(x)|.$$ It looks like you can take $C = \frac 1n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For a scalar function, Green's Theorem states:
$$\int_D \nabla \cdot \nabla u = \int_{\partial D} \nabla u \cdot n ds$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Could you expand it a little more? And for Green's Theorem: which is the $C^1$-boundary? the boundary of the ball?

Comment: @sheldoor  Yes, my intention is that $D$ is the ball.  And you don't need the first observation about rotational invariance, so I removed it.